# insert files into mysql and directory but only last inserted file is recorded

Tags: php, mysql, file

I have input that stores multiple files in database and directory.

```
<input id="attachment_file" name="attachment_file" type="file" value="<?=$_POST["attachment_file"]?>" class="form-control hidden" multiple />
```

if there are 2 files uploaded i simply want to record them in db and move them to other directory, but the weird thing is that the record is only of the last file that is inserted ...
Here is some code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['attachment_file']); $i++) { 
        
        $file_name = $_FILES["attachment_file"]["name"][$i];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['attachment_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $docs_dir = F_FS_PATH_USER_PHOTOS."files/docs/";

        if(!is_dir($docs_dir)) {
            mkdir($docs_dir, 0777, true);
            chmod($docs_dir, 0777);
        }

        $new_dir = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $docs_dir.$file_name);
        $docs_url = F_WS_PATH_USER_PHOTOS."files/docs/".$_FILES["attachment_file"]["name"][$i];

        
     
        
        query("INSERT INTO orders_documents SET
        id = NULL,
        date_added = now(),
        order_id =".forsql($order_id).",
        doc_type =".forsql($_FILES["attachment_file"]["type"][$i]).",
        doc_url =".forsql($docs_url).",
        doc_id =".forsql('1').",
        doc_name =".forsql($_FILES["attachment_file"]["name"][$i]));
    }
```

i also tried to insert 3 files "random.pdf","alter_tables.txt","testfile.txt" and simply check if all files are stored in $_FILE variable like:

```
print_r($_FILES);
        exit();
```

but the answer i get is:

```
    Array
(
    [attachment_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => testfile.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpB3DC.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 150
        )
)
```

and like i said i get record in db and directory only of this file but not the other 2 ?

i tryed to add [] to the input name but nothing changed ?
i litteraly dont know what else should i try to check why store only last one file in $_FILES

also the form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? As far as I see, you don't execute the query in the given code. Also, be warned that the code is widely open for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: if there arent record in $_FILES variable of all inserted files, what else should i try ?

Comment: And how you realized I hadn't executed it ?

Comment: The PHP manual has a page on [Uploading multiple files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: i saw the page already but it didnt helped me ...

Comment: Why did you edit your post to be just gibberish?

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your posts (edited back)!

Comment: "And how you realized I hadn't executed it" - you haven't shared any such code, so this was just a guess. If you **did** execute it, please share the code involved, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the `input` must show that you will receive an array. Change it to `attachment_file[]` to allow the array to be passed back to your server.

```
<input id="attachment_file" name="attachment_file[]" type="file" value="<?=$_POST["attachment_file"]?>" class="form-control hidden" multiple />
```

Comment: i tried that but nothing changed

Comment: the print($_FILES); is still the same with 1 file in it

Comment: You have only 1 array entry BUT you have multiple entries for `name`, `type` etc.